# Is it possible to improve the speed where parallelization is not efficient?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, table

I tried to use `Parallelize` but did not boost the speed. how can improve the speed?

```
boundR[v1_, v2_, {x_, y_}] := 
  MinimalBy[
    Flatten[Table[{x, y} + i v1 + j v2, {i, -1, 0}, {j, -1, 0}], 1], 
    Norm][[1]];
getfinponts[v1_, v2_, nnc_] := 
 Block[{final}, 
  Rpoints = 
   Flatten[Table[{i/nnc, j/nnc} . {v1, v2} 1., {j, 0., nnc - 1}, {i, 
      0., nnc - 1}], 1];
  final = boundR[v1, v2, #] & /@ Rpoints;
  Return[final]]
```

for arbitrary vectors  `v1 = {-3.14, -1.81}; v2 = {-3.14, 1.81}`,  I am aiming for `ncc=600`, but for `ncc=300` it takes `5.3` sec on my laptop Win64 MMA12.3.

```
getfinponts[v1, v2, 300]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why `MinimalBy` is so slow. However, the following function speeds up things considerably:

```
cf = Compile[{{Rpoints, _Real, 1}, {shifts, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{m, min, x0, x, xmin, y0, y, ymin, normSquared},
    m = Length[shifts];
    
    x0 = Compile`GetElement[Rpoints, 1];
    y0 = Compile`GetElement[Rpoints, 2];
    
    xmin = x = x0 + Compile`GetElement[shifts, 1, 1];
    ymin = y = y0 + Compile`GetElement[shifts, 1, 2];
    min = x x + y y;
    
    Do[
     x = x0 + Compile`GetElement[shifts, j, 1];
     y = y0 + Compile`GetElement[shifts, j, 2];
     
     normSquared = x x + y y;
     
     If[normSquared < min,
      min = normSquared;
      xmin = x;
      ymin = y;
      ];
     , {j, 2, m}];
    
    {xmin, ymin}
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now you can do:

```
nnc = 300;
v1 = {-3.14, -1.81};
v2 = {-3.14, 1.81};

First@AbsoluteTiming[
 Rpoints = Tuples[Most[Subdivide[0., 1., nnc]], 2] . {v1 , v2};
 shifts = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray[
   Flatten[Table[i v1 + j v2, {i, -1, 0}, {j, -1, 0}], 1]];
 final = cf[Rpoints, shifts];
 ]
```

> 0.005717

Comment: Do you not need a C-compiler Mathematica can access to run that code?

Comment: Yes, of course. You do. ( You can also change `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` to use the Wolfram Virtual Machine, but that is typically not as fast.)